# Which design pattern should we use for category of tenants / users?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm, design-patterns

Existed Code -
We can perform CRUD on tenant and also we have business method for same in business layer.
**Who can perform actions against tenant** - Restricted to two users (Role_A & Role_B).
TenantController -> TenantService -> TenantDAO

New Scenario -
Now we are introducing tenantCategory so older tenants will be known as Tenant_A and new tenants will be known as Tenant_B.

What we did -
Used If else in same TenantService code and did what was required for new use case.

- Skip few fields
- Added few new fields
- Added new validations
- Did authorization in same method using if else as initially we were allowing two users (A & B).We used @PreAuthorization but for this new tenant only B can perform the actions.

What can be do better -
Can use design pattern to separate the flow. I did some research and get to know suitable design pattern are -

1. Strategy
2. Decorator
3. Visitor

But still not sure which one is suitable pattern.

**Techstack** - Java 11 & Spring Boot

Comment: It's hard to tell without having more details but strategy might look good. Do you have a basic understanding of those patterns and an idea of how they'd fit your needs? If so, select the one that's easier to use and understand for you and your team.

Comment: When you do CRUD on tenants, what filters do you want to allow for reading, update and delete ? If `tenantCategory` is one of those fields, then strategy seems good